# Return Value of put() in HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, syntax

I was having trouble understanding the explanation for return value of `put()` in a `HashMap`:

```
  private Map<Bookmark, Integer> mDevice = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    String abc = "two"
    Integer ret = mDevice.put(abc, ONLINE);
```

Am I correct in saying the following:

1. if abc key already exists with value `OFFLINE`, ret is equal to `OFFLINE`.
2. if abc key already exists with value `ONLINE`, ret is equal to `ONLINE`.
3. if abc key did not exist, then ret is equal to `null`.

Comment: this is a legitimate question, why the -1?

Comment: Read the javadocs.  Your understanding is quite incorrect: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: see that's why i asked...so why the negative votes.

Comment: "previous value associated with specified key, or null if there was no mapping for key". It is quite clear.

Comment: isn't that what i have written above in t he question.

Comment: It's really simple: if there was already an entry in the map for the specified key, it returns the value of that old entry; if not, it returns `null`. So yes, what you write is correct. Don't make it more complicated than it is.

Comment: Upvoted, because no explanation for downvote is given in comments so far.

Comment: Why I downvoted : The javadoc is clear. Basically any answer will be, yes you are both right and a rephrasing of the javadoc. Oh look, just when I say it...

Comment: @UmNyobe After reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168052/should-we-allow-questions-that-are-simple-obvious, I tend to agree...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The method put has a return type same with the value:

```
    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return putImpl(key, value);
    }
```

The method associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.

It returns the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key.So, your points are right.

For more details please visit [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 2):

```java
package com.payu.Payu;

import java.util.*;

public class HashMap_Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Creating an empty HashMap
        HashMap<Integer, String> hashmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        // Mapping string values to int keys
        hashmap.put(10, "HashMap");
        hashmap.put(15, "4");
        hashmap.put(25, "You");

        // Displaying the HashMap
        System.out.println("Initial Mappings are: " + hashmap);

        // Inserting existing key along with new value
        // return type of put is type of values i.e. String and containing the old value 
        String returned_value = hashmap.put(10, "abc");

        // Verifying the returned value
        System.out.println("Returned value is: " + returned_value);

        // Inserting new key along with new value
        // return type of put is type of values i.e. String ; since it is new key ,return value will be null

        returned_value = hashmap.put(20, "abc");

        // Verifying the returned value
        System.out.println("Returned value is: " + returned_value);

        // Displayin the new map
        System.out.println("New map is: " + hashmap);
    }
}
```

Output :-

Initial Mappings are: `{25=You, 10=HashMap, 15=4}`
Returned value is: `HashMap`
Returned value is: `null`
New map is: `{20=abc, 25=You, 10=abc, 15=4}`

Comment: return type of hashmap.put(key,value)   is return type of 'value'  in hashmap.put(key,value)  where hashmap is defined as follows :- HashMap<Integer,String> hashmap = new HashMap<Integer,String>(); so return type of  hashmap.put(key,value) is String,always .

Comment: Can you add some more explanation to the answer rather than pasting your code and the output? I don't see the need for so much code and almost no explanation.

Comment: @razdi If you read the code carefully you will find the meaning between the lines. Code itself explains all

Comment: @IshanPatel I totally agree with you, coe itself explains all :)

Answer (score 0):

When we call HashMap put method:

If the map is not associated with any value the return type is **null** else the **previous associated value** is returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hash_Map.put(key, value)
```

> Return Value: If an existing key is passed then the previous value
> gets returned.  If a new pair is passed, then NULL is returned.